# How to increase Real VNC session screen resolution on Windows?

Tags: windows, vnc-server

I have a Windows Server 2012 (a VMWare virtual machine) that runs RealVNC 5.2.2 server as a service. I have no problem connecting to the server, but when I try to set "Screen resolution", the maximum I can get is 1280x800.

The VM has 256MB of video memory so it should be able to support a higher resolution (1680x1050 is more desirable).

Does anyone know what's controlling the maximum resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what's wrong. The SVGA 3D property page shows 256MB of video memory, but in fact, the VM was originally assigned 4MB of video memory by administrator. Once I changed it to 8MB, I can bump up the resolution as needed.